# Angular MatMenu: highlighting active item

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to highlight the element in the MenuItem that is active right now, the one where the user is present at the moment.

For example: I am navigating to the profile page. Then I want this menu entry to be highlighted. I've tried it with some HTML and TypeScript but somehow it bugs like hell:

**StackBlitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vgp585

**HTML**:

```html
 <mat-toolbar color="primary" style="height:67px;">
   <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
     <button mat-menu-item id="settings" *ngIf="authenticationService.currentUserValue" [routerLink]="['/settings']"
       (click)="setActiveItem('settings')">
       <mat-icon [ngStyle]="{'color' : activeItem===settings ? 'blue' : 'rgba(0,0,0,.54)' }">settings</mat-icon>
       <span
         [ngStyle]="{'font-weight': activeItem===settings ? 'bold' : 'normal' }">{{ 'HEADER.SETTINGS' | translate }}</span>
     </button>
     <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="authenticationService.currentUserValue" [routerLink]="['/profile']"
       (click)="setActiveItem('profile')">
       <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'address-card']"
         [ngStyle]="{'color' : activeItem===profile ? 'blue' : 'rgba(0,0,0,.54)' }" class="font-awesome" size="lg">
       </fa-icon>
       <span
         [ngStyle]="{'font-weight': activeItem===profile ? 'bold' : 'normal' }">{{ 'HEADER.PROFILE' | translate }}</span>
     </button>
     <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="authenticationService.currentUserValue" [matMenuTriggerFor]="subMenu">
       <mat-icon>language</mat-icon>
       <span>{{ 'HEADER.LANGUAGE' | translate }}</span>
     </button>
     <button mat-menu-item>
       <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
       <span>{{ 'HEADER.DISABLEALERTS' | translate }}</span>
     </button>
     <button mat-menu-item (click)="logout()" [routerLink]="['/chat']">
       <fa-icon style="color: rgba(0,0,0,.54)" [icon]="['fas', 'sign-out-alt']" class="font-awesome" size="lg"></fa-icon>
       <span>{{ 'HEADER.LOGOUT' | translate }}</span>
     </button>
   </mat-menu>
   <mat-menu #subMenu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
     <button mat-menu-item [ngStyle]="{'color':lang === translate.currentLang ? 'blue' : 'black' }"
       *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()" (click)="translate.use(lang)">{{ lang }}</button>
   </mat-menu>
 </mat-toolbar>
```

**TypeScript**:

```js
   activeItem: string;
 
   setActiveItem(page: string) {
     this.activeItem = page;
   }
```

Is there no possbility to do it with some CSS or something? I dont really know why this does not work.

Thats what it looks like before pressing any button

[image: Thats what it looks like before pressing any button]

[image: After pressing one of the both buttons both change to that]

After pressing one of the both buttons both change to that

Comment: I just looked at the documents and found a better way if you are navigating with this links and want to show which one is open! https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive. Just use this: `<a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive">
  Bob {{ rla.isActive ? '(already open)' : ''}}
</a>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there youself... I had to put quotes around conditions in the `[ngStyle]` to get your code to work

relevant **HTML**:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" style="height:67px;">
    MatMenuStyle
    <button mat-fab [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" >
    <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'address-card']"
       class="font-awesome" size="lg">
        </fa-icon>
  </button>

  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item id="settings"
      (click)="setActiveItem('settings')">
            <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'cog']"
        [ngStyle]="{'color' : activeItem==='settings' ? 'blue' : 'rgba(0,0,0,.54)' }" class="font-awesome" size="lg">
      </fa-icon>
      <span
        [ngStyle]="{'font-weight': activeItem===settings ? 'bold' : 'normal' }"> SETTINGS</span>
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item 
      (click)="setActiveItem('profile')">
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'address-card']"
        [ngStyle]="{'color' : activeItem==='profile' ? 'blue' : 'rgba(0,0,0,.54)' }" class="font-awesome" size="lg">
      </fa-icon>
      <span
        [ngStyle]="{'font-weight': activeItem===profile ? 'bold' : 'normal' }">PROFILE</span>
    </button>
  </mat-menu>
</mat-toolbar>
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7c583?file=src/app/app.component.html)